# Run a same celery task in loop

Tags: python, celery

how to run this kind of celery task properly?

```
@app.task
def add(x)
    x + 1


def some_func():
    result = 'result'
    for i in range(10):
        task_id = uuid()
        add.apply_async((i,)), task_id=task_id)
    return result
```

I need all tasks to be performed sequentially after the previous one is completed.
I tried using time.sleep() but in this case returning result waits until all tasks are completed. But I need the result returned and all 10 tasks are running sequentially in the background.

there is a group() in celery, but it runs tasks in parallel

Comment: Try [chains](https://docs.celeryproject.org/en/stable/userguide/canvas.html#chains), but will depends on what are trying to accomplish, maybe you need periodic tasks.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

If some_func() is executed outside Celery (say a script is used as "producer" to just send those tasks to be executed), then nothing stops you from calling .get() on AsyncResult to wait for task to finish, and loop that as much as you like.

If, however, you want to execute that loop as some sort of Celery workflow, then you have to build a [Chain](https://docs.celeryproject.org/en/stable/userguide/canvas.html#chains) and use it.

Comment: When I use .get() it waits until all tasks will finish. But I need to return the result but run tasks in the background. So, for this, do I need to use chain?

Comment: Yes, as it seems it is part of the Celery workflow.

Answer (score 2):

Finally, I solved it by using immutable signature and chain

```
tasks = [
    add.si(x).set(task_id=uuid())
    for x in range(10)
]
chain(*tasks).apply_async()
```